# calculate stack size of C program

Tags: c, stack, stack-trace

I develop program for openwrt embedded device.

I want to print the stack size of my C program when it running.

it is possible to do this ? and how ?

the size of the binary file is `1056967 bytes`

Comment: What binary file? If the exe, that's neither here nor there.

Comment: stack size as in currently being used by the process or currently available?

Comment: @haris : the stack size currently used by the process